# Getting the error: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'" when using Dataframe.apply()

Tags: apply

I am trying to improve performance of my stock order placer algorithm (1000's of lines) by switching from using iterrows() to using apply(), but I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: ("place_orders() missing 1 required positional argument: 'row'", 'occurred at index 2008-01-14 00:00:00')
```

Below is an example of the orders file I am reading in (short list for simplicity):
[image: Orders file]

Next...below is my code both my attempt at implementing apply() and the slower iterrows()

[image: code example using apply and iterrows]

I apologize if this is a newbie question, but I need to use the index and the rows inside the function, as the index is a bunch of dates.

Update: Below is an example of my prices_table.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When switching from `iterrows` to `apply` you need to change your mindset a little bit. Instead of a looping over the dataframe and taking every row from top to bottom, you just specify what you want to happen in every row. Mostly just let go of row numbers.

So when using `apply` it's usually a good idea to let go of of row numbers (in you case `i`). Try using a function like this in your `apply`:

```
orders_df.apply(lambda row: place_orders(row), axis=1)
```

I realize that inside your `place_orders` function you are using specific (sets of) rows of the `prices_table`. To overcome this part you might want to merge the dataframes before calling `apply`, since `apply` is not really intended to work on multiple dataframes at once.

This forces you to rewrite some of your code, but in my experience the performance increase you gain from not using `iterrows` is always worth it.

Comment: Hi Erik.  Thanks for your comments.  I tried using the lambda but I am still getting the same error.  Th problem is that I need to use the index (i) from the order_df as this contains the order days.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to use apply, I think it's better to take the logic of matching orders_df and prices_table outside the apply. I can update my answer with a more detailed code snippet if you share a small sample of the prices_table dataframe.

Comment: Hi Erik.  Thanks for all your help.,  I have updated the original posting with a snippet of my prices_table.